# Matlab quadratic equation/convolution

Tags: matlab, plot, signals, convolution

I've got a convolution where the final result is
y=(-t/2)+5t=6

Is there any chance to check this in matlab but not through convolution, I have programmed that part. What I am wondering is it possible to plot the signal using this equation and compare it with the one that I got with coding convolution.

Answer (score 1):

You can plot functions easily in matlab: look at the examles from [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html).

For example using this code:

```
t = 0:.1:10
plot(t,(-t/2)+5*t)
```

will plot you your function between the values `x = [0, 10]`.